# Check if string in list of objects

Tags: python, django

This is my list

```
[<CorrectEntry: CorrectEntry object>, <CorrectEntry: CorrectEntry object>, <CorrectEntry: CorrectEntry object>]
```

CorrectEntry objects looks like this :

```
number 
message
etc
```

How would I check if a any of those objects in a list has a number that I am checking for?

So I want to check if the number ex. 123 is in any of the objects in the list?

Comment: Is you list a queryset? If yes, then it is better to use `filter, or `values_list` in your situation

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`any()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) with a generator expression:

```
if any(ce.number == yourvaluetotest for ce in correct_entries):
    #
```

The function will loop over the generator expression until a true-ish value is returned, after which itself returns `True`. If no such value is found, `False` is returned instead. This is very efficient, as it will only test as many `CorrectEntry` values as needed to determine that there is one that matches.

Comment: Works perfectly, great python